# Is there any physical significance for the Cremona group / birrational transformations on the projective plane?

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry, the [Cremona group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_group) is the group of birational transformations on the projective plane.

I would like to know:
Is there any physical interpretation for this group?

Does this group somehow appear in any physical theory?